# Restarting program running in the background and still make it consume from stdin

Tags: bash, shell, tee

This is an extension of previous question I had asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845855/how-to-tee-multiple-times-to-a-single-file-and-program)

```
{
 python2 readLines.py &
 python2 readLines.py &
 python2 readLines.py &
 python2 readLines.py &
 python2 readLines.py &
} | tee  output_file | java program
```

I have been successfully using the script to serve my purpose(it may not be correct as per programming principles)

I am executing the script as follows

```
./script.sh &
```

**Question**

Is there any way to restart just the java program part of above set up?

**Attempts**

- As soon as, the `program` was stopped, the entire script comes down.
- Tried a simple program in python reading from `stdin` and printing the data. Executed in one window of `tmux` session. Tried writing to `stdout` from another window in the session on the same host command prompt, which did not work (proving I need to read more about `stdin` as such). This was to see if writing the data to file + `stdout` and reading from `stdin` can be separated if at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not; restarting the standard input consumer requires the ability of that consumer to `exec` itself.

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[1];
    int ret;
    int linenumber = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "collect me some input...\n");
    while (1) {
        ret = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 1);       // unbuffered. inefficient
        if (ret == 0)           // EOF
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        else if (ret < 0)
            err(1, "read failed");

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, 1);

        if (buf[0] == '\n') {
            linenumber++;
            if (linenumber == 4) {      // restart ourself every four lines...
                execvp(*argv, argv);
                err(1, "exec failed");
            }
        }
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Which when run restarts itself every four lines:

```
$ make execself
cc     execself.c   -o execself
$ perl -E 'say "line $_" for 1..8' | ./execself
collect me some input...
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
collect me some input...
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
collect me some input...
$
```

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that a socket or [message queue](https://github.com/kahun/awesome-sysadmin#queuing) might better suit the need to randomly kill off and restart the consumer of output, as then the messages would (up to a buffer limit or with blocking...) stick around while the consumer process is being killed off and restarted. Or you could write a proxy of some sort that reads standard input and is tolerant of the subsequent java consumer being randomly not available, or to be able to more or less gracefully restart said consumer.

(Note that with buffered reads, the consumer may need to take additional pains to process or somehow pass along whatever incomplete data got read by the buffered read but has not been dealt with at time of restart or exit...)